# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x - e^{-x}}{x} \mathrm dx$ Evaluate Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x - e^{-x}}{x} \ dx$$

Comment: If you evaluate this at 1 you get that C is your integral, so you can't get rid of it.

Comment: If you use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212101/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x-e-x2x-dx/212238#212238),the answer is zero.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal: that's true! Thanks. However, I try to evaluate it by using  differentiation under the integral sign. It would be interesting to know how to get rid of $C$ and finish it up this way.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Can you show your working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use your technique:
$$J(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x-e^{-x}}{x}e^{-ax}dx$$
then 
$$dJ/da=\int_0^\infty(\cos x e^{-ax} -e^{-(1+a)x})dx=a/(a^2+1)-1/(a+1)$$
hence $J(a)=\frac12\log(a^2+1)-\log(a+1)+C$. $C$ can be determined by $J(a)\to 0$ as $a\to\infty$, hence $C=0$ and $J(0)=0$.

Comment: It remains to show that $\int^\infty_0\frac{\cos x-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$ indeed converges (as an improper integral) so that the limit $a\rightarrow0$ can be moved inside the integral. For example $\int^\infty_0e^{-at}\cos x\,dx=\frac{a}{a^s+1}\rightarrow0$ as $a\rightarrow0$ however $\int^\infty_0\cos x\,dx$ does not converge (as an improper integral)

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^\infty  {{{\cos x - {e^{ - x}}} \over x}dx}  = \int_0^\infty  {\left( {{s \over {1 + {s^2}}} - {1 \over {1 + s}}} \right)ds}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{s \to \infty } \log {{\sqrt {{s^2} + 1} } \over {s + 1}} = 0$$

Comment: Maybe some words about the Laplace Transform being taken? Where did the $x^{-1}$ term go?