# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x} dx = 0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I have to show that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x}}{x} dx = 0 
$$ using a quarter circle in the upper positive plane and the function $f(z) = {e^{iz}}/{z}$.

I think I have a solution where I take a quarter-annulus of big radius $R$ and little radius $r$ on the quarter circle, and show they both tend to $0$ as $R \rightarrow 
\infty $ and $r \rightarrow 0$. However, I'm not sure how to manipulate the function $f$ to add in the $-e^{-x}$ term. I also know that $f(z) = 0$ by Cauchy's theorem.

Thus far I think I have a solution with the function $ f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-x}}{z} $ but I am not sure this is the correct way of tackling the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can use that $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

Comment: In the first quadrant, your integrand gets arbitrarily large in absolute value as $|z| \to \infty$ (a consequence of the $e^{-iz}$ term in the complex definition of $\cos$). I'm not sure that approach will be easy.

Comment: Though I have a sneaking suspicion that an integral over a semi-circular contour in the upper half-plane may allow some of the divergent integrals to cancel each other.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217263/int-0-infty-frac-cos-x-e-xx-mathrm-dx-evaluate-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Or use the Cantarini-Frullani's theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807193/evaluating-the-integral-of-frac-cosx-e-xx-using-contour-integratio