# Integrate $(\cos(x)-e^{-x^2})/x$

Tags: integration

How does one integrate the following? $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)-e^{-x^2}}{x} dx$$ Is it possible to do this without using mellintransformation?

Comment: You can use Laplace transform instead. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/evaluate-int-0-infty-left-fracx-textex-texte-x/295326#295326).

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212101/int-0-infty-frac-cos-x-e-x2x-dx-evaluate-integral/212238#212238) is the same problem which uses the Mellin transform.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks Mhenni!

Comment: You are welcome.